# Create an Array and Populate it with values in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to insert an array named `favCakes` inside my JavaScript file and populate it with the values "Butter Cream," "Chocolate," "Vanilla," and "Red Velvet." How do I approach this?

Comment: Insert oops, I'll edit.

Comment: @Civori, surely a v v simple google search would have provided the answer

Comment: It's *right there* in the top of the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: Go back and read the first chapter of your basic JS tutorial again. What's next, asking on SO how to add two numbers in JS?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: `arr=["Butter Cream", "Chocolate", "Vanilla", "Red Velvet"]`

Comment: @torazaburo That's easy. jQuery obviously.

Comment: @torazaburo That's easy! Just use the jQuery arithmetic plugin! https://github.com/cbrandolino/jQuery-basic-arithmetic-plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you should use generators.

```
function generate_flavors* () {
    yield "Butter Cream";
    yield "Chocolate";
    yield "Vanilla";
    yield "Red Velvet";
 }
```

Now you can create your array in any of several ways:

```
console.log(Array.from(generate_flavors()))

console.log(...generate_flavors())

console.log([for (flavor of generate_flavors()) flavor])
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

to insert elements use push function

```
favCakes.push("Butter Cream");
favCakes.push("Chocolate");
```

if favCakes is not declared, use

```
var favCakes = [];
```

or with initialization on declaration

```
var favCakes =["Butter Cream","Chocolate", "Vanilla","Red Velvet"];
```

Comment: Assuming that the variable is already declared. He asks how to insert elements.